# Performance metrics for Vuejs

Tags: javascript, performance, vue.js, frontend, vuex

I'm looking for performance metrics for a Vue app. Metrics regarding the whole app but also for some specific components.

I know that I can use `Vue.config.performance = true;` and then run the performance dev tools and maybe I could use something like [Performance Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceObserver) in order to do specific things on new performance events.

I was wondering, if there are any libraries or services that could help or provide more metrics regarding the performance.
The idea would be to have a ui with these metrics and could be visible for non-devs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [web-vitals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-vitals) library from the npm. It supports core web vitals metrics:

- [Largest contenfull paint](https://web.dev/i18n/en/lcp/) ,
- [First input delay](https://web.dev/fid/)
- [Cumulative layout shift](https://web.dev/cls/)

Example will be looks like this:

```js
import { getLCP, getFID, getCLS } from "web-vitals";

const reporter = (result) => console.log(result);

getCLS(reporter);
getFID(reporter);
getLCP(reporter);
```

Inside handler you can log the result to the console or send them your report system for further analysis.

It's also possible to get CDN version from [here](https://unpkg.com/web-vitals/dist/web-vitals.iife.js)